# Android Input Method / custom emoticons

Tags: android, keyboard

I am trying to create a custom IME for Android, with custom emoticoons that are really just images showing on the keys.

Sending text from the keyboard to the focused text field is easy, by using the `InputConnection` in the `KeyboardActionListener`

```
InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code),1);
```

However sending images is quite challenging. I've seen the keyboard example suggested by many answer in SO (https://github.com/chiragjain/Emoticons-Keyboard) and a few other examples, and it always uses a method similar to this:

```
Spanned cs = Html.fromHtml("<img src ='"+ index +"'/>", imageGetter, null);         
int cursorPosition = content.getSelectionStart();       
content.getText().insert(cursorPosition, cs);
```

While this seems to work well if the focused text field is in part of the activity created by the programmer, it does not work with the OS text field (e.g. it adds an empty square instead of the image when trying to add the image to an EMail message I am writing).

I also tried other methods to send my custom image from the virtual keyboard when pressed. I tried using the clipboard to copy-paste the binary of the image and the link, but it did not work.

I tried sending an intent with the image after saving it to the media library. This works better, it lets the user choose the app to receive the image and when the app receives it, the image is properly displayed. However, it always creates a new message. For example, I am in the email app, open the custom keyboard and select an image. This launches the intent, which brings the chooser. I choose mail, and the image is added to a new message instead of the one I am currently editing.

I am now running out of ideas. Is it even possible to have custom emoticoones / images displayed on the virtual keyboard with a reliable way to send them to the OS applications?